# Mirror exportOptions.plist to Jenkinsfile?

Tags: xcode, build, jenkins-pipeline

First of all I am new to Jenkins, trying to figure out what has been done prior to my approach. Thinking of how can I improve current pipeline.

I have an iOS project with 4 different build targets, different provisioning profile on each. In my jenkinsfile I have a pipeline with a few stages, I also have a defined path to my exportOptions.plist that has all provisioning profile ids.

exportOptions.plist is being used on stage where it creates 4 different IPA, it being passed as an option to -exportOptionsPlist on each of 4 lines;

prior to that on stage where it creates archives I have to hardcode parameters like PROVISIONING_PROFILE on each of 4 lines;

Is it possible to grab PROVISIONING_PROFILE string from exportOptions.plist?

```js
        stage('create arch') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
                            sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project myApp/myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp_DEV -configuration Distribution -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH_1 + ' TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1,2" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: myCompany" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="1234567890" archive'
                    }
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'release') {
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project myApp/myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp_1 -configuration Distribution -archivePath '     + XCARCHIVE_PATH         + ' TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1,2" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: myCompany" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="0987654321" archive'
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project myApp/myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp_DEV -configuration Distribution -archivePath '      + XCARCHIVE_PATH_1      + ' TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1,2" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: myCompany" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="1234567890" archive'
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project myApp/myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp_2 -configuration Distribution -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH_2 + ' TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1,2" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: myCompany" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="0987612345" archive'
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project myApp/myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp_3 -configuration Distribution -archivePath '     + XCARCHIVE_PATH_3     + ' TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1,2" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: myCompany" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="5432109876" archive'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('create ipa') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
                            sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH_1 + ' -exportPath ' + TARGET_IPA_PATH + ' -exportOptionsPlist ' + EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST_PATH
                    }
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'release') {
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH + ' -exportPath ' + TARGET_IPA_PATH + ' -exportOptionsPlist ' + EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST_PATH
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH_1 + ' -exportPath ' + TARGET_IPA_PATH + ' -exportOptionsPlist ' + EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST_PATH
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH_2 + ' -exportPath ' + TARGET_IPA_PATH + ' -exportOptionsPlist ' + EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST_PATH
                        sh '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ' + XCARCHIVE_PATH_2 + ' -exportPath ' + TARGET_IPA_PATH + ' -exportOptionsPlist ' + EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST_PATH
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It feels wrong that profile ids are being hardcoded in two places 1) exportOptions 2) jenkinsfile

Comment: Not an expert with iOS. But from the generic use case, I highly encourage you to maintain the versions in a separate file such as a `yaml` file. Then, import the file and read content from that. First of all, it helps you to separate the concerns. Secondly, you can reuse the same properties in multiple places. Finally, it is neat.

Comment: As far as I understand they all are maintained in Xcode itself, which then exports the *.plist. I just want Jenkins to pick them up accordingly from that plist.